# how to make JavaScript read files name in a spacific folder?

Tags: javascript, php, python, file, web

I want to make a slide show with images in it 
and i want the JS code to read the files name in a spacific folder and show it in the website 
so how can i do that 
note that i'm using it for a site and if it won't be done using this programing language which languag should i use other than it ? 
PHP, python, etc

Comment: @Skynet, unfortunately adding more tags will not invite "more quality responses for the question". It is too broad already.

Comment: @Frederic thanks for let me know, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: I didn't add them someone edited it and i allowed it since i didn't which language would be able to do this job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP or any other server side language to read the contents of the directory then output the required markup so that JavaScript can handle slideshow.

With PHP you will use `scan_dir` to read contents of a directory.

Comment: I see than i should use JS to get the array of file names as images direction right

Comment: Yes, this could be a JSON object or the full markup for slideshow, depends on how you want to code it.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be in javascript?

You can use the php function [glob](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) to read a folder like this:

```
// the * means you want all files in this folder
$path = '/var/www/example/example_dir/*';  

// will return you an array with the content of this folder
$files = glob($path);
```

Comment: then i will use this arrat in JS code to show the images titles and with that i have slide show right ?